# PDO not giving a error response in try/catch

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have some some PDO code and even if the row isn't successfully inserted into the DB it doesn't give an error...

```
try {
    $options = [
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    ];
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO reservations (bookingdatetime, remoteip) 
                                  VALUES (:bookingdatetime, :remoteip)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':bookingdatetime', $bookingdatetime);
    $stmt->bindParam(':remoteip', $remoteip);

    // insert a row
    $stmt->execute();

    $bookingid = $conn->lastInsertId();

    echo json_encode(array("title" => "WE DID IT!", "body" => " The row # " . $bookingid . " was made!"))

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo json_encode(array("title" => "Database Error", "body" => $e->getMessage()));
}
$conn = null;
```

Edit: I should say that even if the row isn't successfully created it still gives a "we did it!" message, and the row id is returned as 0

Edit 2: if I put a type on my prepare statement column names, it will still return a "WE DID IT"... that would be an obvious error.

Comment: maybe its not a `PDOException`, try change to `Exception`

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ Edit: I should say that even if the row isn't successfully created it still gives a "we did it!" message, and the row id is returned as 0

Comment: what's the value of echo $stmt;?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a function `rowCount` which states the number of rows inserted/updated by previous query

```
$stmt->execute();
$rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();

$bookingid = $conn->lastInsertId();

if($rowCount > 0)
    echo json_encode(array("title" => "WE DID IT!", "body" => " The row # " . $bookingid . " was made!"));
else 
    echo json_encode(array("title" => "Database Error", "body" =>"Insert Failed"));
```